MCMC for correlated Posterior
I'm simulating the posterior of a (as it seems) highly correlated Posterior distribution using MCMC (DREAM Algorithm).
My setting is that I have 7 parameters where x1/x3 and x2/x4 is highly correlated, which is physically logical.
However, during the run, either x3 or x4 pushes towards the lower boundary, i.e. towards zero. However, I cannot allow negative values, as this is physically impossible and evaluation would fail. So, I suppose the problem is of algorithmic nature.
The Scatterplots of the parameters are attached. Here, x4 always pushes to unrealistically low values.
Can anyone give me a hint how this behavior of the MCMC algorithm can be prevented?
Is reparametrization an option and how can this be done?
Thank you very much!



Do I understand your issue correctly: you want to prevent certain parameters from being negative? The easy fix is simply to reject any proposal with a negative value (before even evaluating the likelihood). This may be interpreted as using a prior density of zero on the negative half-line. Or, as you mention, you could parameterize on the log scale, so let the MCMC pick any value it wants, and in your likelihood do $x_4 \gets e^{x_4}$ at the very top. If by "unrealistic value", you mean small but positive, we have a very different issue on hand.

I do not see a conceptual difficulty with some parameters being close to zero, since the histogram of $x_4$ is not a point mass at zero. More of a concern are the extremely high correlations between $x_1$ and $x_2$, and between $x_3$ and $x_4$. It would be of interest to rerun an MCMC for a model when $x_2$ is a fixed linear transform of $x_1$ and $x_4$ a fixed linear transform of $x_3$ to check if the other distributions change.

Dear John, dear Xi'an,
thank you for your suggestions and questions.
My problem is actually, that the value for x3 or x4 alsways falls rapidly to zero, even though this is physically very unlikely.
To see, whether this is a question of convergence (even if I have difficulty in explainig that the chains always pushes to zero), I'm currently rerunning the simulation with a lot more samples. I hope this will help, but due to the required computational time for each sample, this will take a while.
I will let you know what is the outcome.
Do you have any explanation for x ->0?
